# How to start on booting "rvmsudo rails server" command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I am trying to configure my own "Thingspeak" server on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS virtual machine. I introduced this commands on terminal (installation on clean install of ubuntu): `https://github.com/iobridge/ThingSpeak` but at the final I use:

```
rvmsudo rails server -d -b <myip> -p 80
```

This command let me run Thingspeak app on port 80 as a daemon. It works well, but when the server reboot (sudo reboot  for example) the thingspeak server shut down and I don't want this, I want to automatically (on booting or startup) start the thingspeak server so I don't need to manually use in terminal the rvmsudo command again.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Regarding your post deleted just now: if you have a problem that is different to an existing one, please post a new question. You will need to post all the necessary information, including your code/logs/error etc. in order to have a good chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to:

```
       /etc/rc.local
       rvmsudo rails server -d -b -p 80
```

or add it to /etc/init.d as well

Updating this:

sudo nano /etc/rc.local

Add the following before the exit 0 line:

```
                                  cd <folder path>
                                  rvmsudo rails server -d -b -p 80
```

Comment: hi... i try to add the command in etc/rc.local but nothing happens, i don't know if i am writing it well, can you show me how you write that please?... i probed with /etc/init.d but it is a directory not a file

Comment: did you cd into the directory. In the script cd /var/www/<app folder> and then run the command.

Comment: I updated my previous post using the steps I do for my other applications. Please refer to the updation

Comment: In my case I use a cron, this work for me @reboot /bin/bash -c "source /home/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; cd <folder path> ; rvmsudo rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80 -d"